# If f is a endomorphism and P is a normal Sylow p-subgroup then...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I have earlier this year in January tried some questions in Group theory but couldn't post them due to my illness.

> If $P$ is a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$ and $f\colon G\to G$ is an endomorphism, then prove that $f(P) \lt P$.

Let $x, y \in f(P)$.

I have prove that $f(P )$ is a subgroup. But why is it subgroup of $P$ I am unable to prove it? Can you please tell what property of normal p -subgroups should I use?

thanks

Comment: By Sylow's theorem, $P$ is the *only* Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Now $f(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup, so it is contained in some Sylow $p$-subgroup. But since there is only one, we have $f(P)\le P$.

Comment: Why are you taking $x,y\in f(P)$? To prove that $f(P)\leq P$, you would normally just need to show that any *one* element of $f(P)$ is in $P$.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki Why P should be only sylow p-subgroup of G? As far as I know, the theorems implies converse ie if sylow subgroup is unique then it is normal.So, I think your argument is not valid

Comment: All Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate. So there is only one if and only if it's normal.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki Thanks!

Comment: I think we can do this without Sylow's theorem, just show that $f(P)P\leq G$ and $|f(P)||P|/|f(P)\cap P |\big| |G|\Rightarrow f(P)\subset P$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $P=xPx^{-1}$ for any $x\in G$ ($P$ is normal in $G$). So, if we find an $x\in G$ such that $f(P)<xPx^{-1}$, then we are done. To obtain this, we want to use the second Sylow theorem. Therefore, to use the theorem, we need to show that $f(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$, i.e. the order of each $f(a)\in f(P)$, $a\in P$, is a power of $p$.

Notice that $|f(a)|$ divides $|a|$, where $|a|$ is a power of $p$ ($P$ is a $p$-subgroup). Then $|f(a)|$ is a power of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Following answer is of Brauer Suzuki in comment section. Since comments are temporary, it is better to have answer in answer section.

If $P$ is a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, then $P$ is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. This result follows easily from second Sylow theorem. We claim $f(P)=\{f(x)\mid x\in P\}$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$. Let $x\in P$. Since $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, we have $|x|=p^i$ for some $i\geq 0$. So $x^{p^i}=e_G$. By elementary property of homomorphism, $f(x^{p^i})=f(x)^{p^i}=f(e_G)=e_G$. Which implies $|f(x)|\mid p^i$ and $|f(x)|=p^r$ for some $0\leq r\leq i$. Therefore $f(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$. By (the proof of) first Sylow theorem, $f(P)$ is contained in some Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Since $\exists$ unique $P$ Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, $f(P)\lt P$.